# Double Sum of series in Matlab

Tags: sum, double, matlab, series

I am new to MATLAB . I want to solve the following double summation denoted as 'A'.

```
A= sigma(j=1..n)sigma(k=1..m)x1_ik((x2_ijk - x3_ij(k-1))^2)
```

I do not understand is that loop is the good way to solve the solution or something else. It seems Matlab does not have any built in function for double summation.
What I am using for double summation:

```
sum2=0;
  for i=1:10
      for j=1:10  
         sum2=sum2+(i*j);
       end
   end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized code is often faster in Matlab. Your loop can be vectorized like this:

```
vec1 = 1:10;
vec2 = 1:10;

mat1 = repmat(vec1',1,length(vec2));
mat2 = repmat(vec2,length(vec1),1);

sum(sum(mat1.*mat2))
```